# Are SVN Branching/Merging Options Missing in Xcode 8.3

Tags: xcode, svn, version-control, branch

I'm using Xcode 8.3.3 with SVN. I'm able to connect to an existing repository, make changes, and check in my code. However, It looks like the branching menu items are missing.

I have configured Trunk, Tag, and Branches options; and then was given the option to add branches. But after creating the branch, no changes seem to have been made.

Expected menu (from a training video):
[image]

Actual menu (from my project):
[image]

Note: "mobile" is the name of the working folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVN is still fully supported in XCode 8.3.

The issue I was having above was that the code was not properly matched to the repository location. When the developer clicks "Check Out..." they are presented with the option below. The developer must map to the branch folder.

[image]

As an aside, SVN branching support removed in XCode 9.0. To work around this, the developer can have both versions of XCode installed - switch back to 8.3 (or older) to manage SVN branches.